# Whats the most pythonic way to generate a list of dates from two dates

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of dates (Nth day of the week) between two dates.

For example, given the dates "20111101" and "20111201", Assume I want to generate the 3rd Wednesday of the month dates, I want to generate dates :

```
["20111116", "20111221"]
```

So I want to write a function like this:

```
def generateNthWeekdayDatesList(startdate, enddate, nthday=3, dayofweek="wed"):
    pass
```

Whats the best (i.e. most pythonic) way to implement this function?

Comment: Those are strings, not dates.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Is it possible to obtain the nth day of the week of a string?. I didn't think that I would have to explicitly state that the strings have to be converted to dates first.

Comment: Python has a (well, a couple) native date type. Use that instead, then convert to string on output.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You are stating the obvious. I left out the obvious details for the sake of brevity. How do you for instance, suppose that I show the returned date types?. I simply used strings as input and output because it makes the code snippet shorter and clearer. Its trivial to convert to/from text and datetime - so I'm not sure why you feel coders will find this confusing ...

Comment: What code do you have so far? The solution is straightforward for a beginner, and given your responses to comments you must be at least an expert already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where using a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) is very suitable/pythonic.

```
def nth_day_of_month(start, end, nth, weekday):
    assert start.day == 1, "start on the first day of a month"
    assert nth > 0
    assert 1 <= weekday <= 7

    candidate = start
    seen_in_month = 0
    while candidate <= end:
        if candidate.isoweekday() == weekday:
            seen_in_month += 1
            if seen_in_month == nth:
                yield candidate
                current_month = candidate.month
                while candidate.month == current_month:
                    candidate += timedelta(1)
                seen_in_month = 0
            else:
                if (candidate + timedelta(1)).month != candidate.month:
                    seen_in_month = 0
                candidate += timedelta(1)
        else:
            if (candidate + timedelta(1)).month != candidate.month:
                seen_in_month = 0
            candidate += timedelta(1)


# third wednesday
print list(nth_day_of_month(date(2011, 1, 1), date(2012, 1, 1), nth=3, weekday=3))

# fifth sunday
print list(nth_day_of_month(date(2011, 1, 1), date(2012, 1, 1), nth=5, weekday=7))

# 9th monday
print list(nth_day_of_month(date(2011, 1, 1), date(2012, 1, 1), nth=9, weekday=1))
```

You could even create an infinite generator (one that never stops):

```
def infinite_nth_day_of_month(start, nth, weekday):
    assert start.day == 1, "start on the first day of a month"
    assert nth > 0
    assert 1 <= weekday <= 7

    candidate = start
    seen_in_month = 0
    while True:
        if candidate.isoweekday() == weekday:
            seen_in_month += 1
            if seen_in_month == nth:
                yield candidate
                current_month = candidate.month
                while candidate.month == current_month:
                    candidate += timedelta(1)
                seen_in_month = 0
            else:
                if (candidate + timedelta(1)).month != candidate.month:
                    seen_in_month = 0
                candidate += timedelta(1)
        else:
            if (candidate + timedelta(1)).month != candidate.month:
                seen_in_month = 0
            candidate += timedelta(1)

# this will create an infinite list, not a good idea
# print list(infinite_nth_day_of_month(date(2011, 1, 1), 3, 3))

import itertools

date_generator = infinite_nth_day_of_month(date(2011, 1, 1), 3, 3)
# create a list the 10000 third wednesdays of 2011 and into the future
date_list = list(itertools.islice(date_generator, 10000))

>>> print date_list[0]
2011-01-19
>>> print date_list[-1]
2844-04-20
```

See the docs for [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

The infinite generator is no good if arguments supplied to it creates a generator that never yields anything (for instance 9th tuesday). In that case it will search endlessly until it hits the maximum date supported by `datetime.date` and raise an `OverflowError: date value out of range`.

Comment: I like, I like! :). +1 for the link to generator functions. Book marked for later reading... Quick question though, is there any reason why you restrict the start date to the first of that month?

Comment: BTW, should the weekday argument not be 2 for wednesday?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: I restrict the start date so I won't have to have any special logic to start counting in the middle of a month. Re. the weekday argument: I compare weekday to ``.isoweekday()``, and ``.isoweekday`` returns 1 for monday, 7 for sunday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package.

```
import dateutil.relativedelta as R
import dateutil.parser as P
from datetime import datetime


def generateNthWeekdayDatesList(startdate, enddate, nthday=3, dayofweek=R.WE):
    s = P.parse(startdate).replace(day=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    e = P.parse(enddate)
    while s < e:
        n = s + R.relativedelta(weekday=dayofweek(nthday))
        if s <= n <= e:
            yield n
        s += R.relativedelta(months=1)


def main():
    print list(generateNthWeekdayDatesList("20111116", "20111221"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running it gives me:

```
$ python f.py 
[datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 21, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating by weeks instead of days can be done; it just needs some logic, modulo 7 (not 6!) arithmetic, and test cases to get the correct starting point. The reward for this initial investment is a small `while` loop that is clean and legible. It also should be much faster, if anyone cares.

```
import datetime

def nth_weekdays(startdate, enddate, n, isoweekday):
    """
    Generate in ascending order all dates x
    such that startdate <= x <= enddate
    and x is the nth ISO weekday in its month.
    """
    if not (1 <= n <= 5):
        raise ValueError("n should be 1 to 5, not %r" % n)
    if not (1 <= isoweekday <= 7):  # Monday = 1
        raise ValueError("isoweekday should be 1 to 7, not %r" % isoweekday)
    # get day of week of the first day in the start month
    dow1 = startdate.replace(day=1).isoweekday()
    # get date which is the first Wday in the start month
    daynum = (isoweekday - dow1 + 7) % 7 + 1
    candidate = startdate.replace(day=daynum)
    seen_in_month = 1
    current_month = candidate.month
    one_week = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    while candidate <= enddate:
        if seen_in_month == n and candidate >= startdate:
            yield candidate
        candidate += one_week
        if candidate.month == current_month:
            seen_in_month += 1
        else:
            seen_in_month = 1
            current_month = candidate.month

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pprint import pprint as pp
    tests = """
        2011-01-01 2012-01-01 3 3 # 3rd Wednesday
        2011-06-14 2011-06-30 3 3 # 3rd Wednesday
        2011-06-15 2011-06-30 3 3 # 3rd Wednesday
        2011-06-16 2011-06-30 3 3 # 3rd Wednesday, no results
        2011-01-01 2012-01-01 5 7 # 5th Sunday
        # 2011-12-01 was a Thursday. Check 1st Mon Wed Thu Fri Sun
        2011-12-01 2011-12-31 1 1
        2011-12-01 2011-12-31 1 3
        2011-12-01 2011-12-31 1 4
        2011-12-01 2011-12-31 1 5
        2011-12-01 2011-12-31 1 7
        # 2011-08-01 was a Monday. Check 1st Mon Tue Sun
        2011-08-01 2011-08-31 1 1
        2011-08-01 2011-08-31 1 2
        2011-08-01 2011-08-31 1 7
        # 2011-05-01 was a Sunday. Check 1st Mon Sat Sun
        2011-05-01 2011-05-31 1 1
        2011-05-01 2011-05-31 1 6
        2011-05-01 2011-05-31 1 7
        # input errors
        2011-01-01 2012-01-01 6 1 # 6th Monday
        2011-01-01 2012-01-01 0 1 # 0th Monday
        2011-01-01 2012-01-01 3 0 # 3rd ???day
        2011-01-01 2012-01-01 3 8 # 3rd ???day
    """
    dconv = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
    funcs = [dconv, dconv, int, int]
    for test in tests.splitlines():
        test = test.strip()
        if not test: continue
        print
        print test
        data = test.split("#")[0]
        if not data: continue
        args = [func(x) for func, x in zip(funcs, data.split())]
        try:
            pp([x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in nth_weekdays(*args)])
        except BadArg, e:
            print "%s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, e)
```

Comment: I would use ValueError instead of BadArg. From the docs: exception ValueError: Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

Answer (score -1):

Ah yes - the IMM date problem.

It's an infinite series. So the solution needs to take care of that.

1. Don't use strings, use datetime.date which you can then convert to strings.

I would write something like this.

```
class IMMDate (object):

    @staticmethod
    def next (when):
        '''
        returns the next IMM date after when
        if when is an IMM date it will return the next
        ''''
        ...
```

You might also want to implement a previous method.